# Where to find TCPDump pcap file in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, tcpdump, otrs

I am trying to investigate what is causing "Session invalid. Please log in again" in [OTOBO platform](https://otobo.de/en/).
I therefore  tried taking tcpdump based on this [provided solution](https://www.codeer.dev/blog/2022/01/06/docker-network-traffic-tcpdump.html#:%7E:text=docker%20run%20--rm%20-v%20%24%20%28pwd%29%3A%2Fdump%20--tty%20--net%3Dcontainer%3A%3Ccontainer_name%3E,runs%20tcpdump%20which%20listens%20on%20all%20network%20interfaces.) but what I fail to get is where my file "dump.pcap" is stored, I have checked in the /tmp directories in linux and in the container but I cannot find it.

The tcpdump command I used is `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/dump --tty --net=container:otobo_web_1 tcpdump tcpdump -i any -w /tmp/dump.pcap`
Please me understand where the file is stored.

Comment: It's in `/tmp` in the container-private filesystem, which is lost on exit due to the `docker run --rm` option.  Do you mean to write the dump file to the container's `/dump` directory, which is a bind-mounted host directory?

Comment: Yes @David, I want to save it in the local (ubuntu) tmp directory

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the dump but using a different comamand.
With this, the file is saved in my ubuntu directory

```
docker run --tty --net=container:otobo_web_1 tcpdump | tee /tmp/dump.pcap
```